# Add extension to filename if not already present

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, file-extension

I want to let the user input a filename before downloading a file.

How do I validate the filename and how can I add an extension `.jpg` if the user didn't already enter this?

So if I input `myfilename.jpg`, it shouldn't add anything, but if I input `myfilename`, it should append `.jpg`. If I input `myfilename.`, it should append `jpg`.

I don't know how to control this correctly, because the user could eventually want to use the filename `filename.jp`, and then I don't know if it's bad UX design if I change this to `filename.jpg` instead of `filename.jp.jpg`?

Comment: I don't think there's a *correct* answer for this question (its latest part, anyway), as it relies on subjective evaluation of what's better. Personally, I would recommend **not** adding any extension and leaving it to the browser to decide. My second preferred choice would be to check whether one of the extensions commonly used for the filetype was provided (e.g. **.jpg** or **.jpeg** in your case), and if not, **add** (not replace!) the standard extensions (here, **.jpg**).

Comment: @mortensen have you tried the solution or is it solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex, it will look for perfect match, only having one dot and ends with .jpg

```
 /^([^.]*).jpg$/m
```

if no match then try :

```
   /^([^.]*)$/m
```

if matches then it means user haven't put any extension so you should put .jpg at the end.

else the filename is invalid... note that my observation is to not have more than one period in the regex in the both case, and if there is a period then it is followed by jpg or else there should not be any period.
But it may vary according to customer choice.

apart from that the filename is invalid and you shold not return error message

Comment: This is a very poor regular expression. Why do you require the user not to use dots in the filename? Wouldn't it be better to simply use `.\.jpe?g$` for the regexp?

Comment: Multiple dots in filename could cause problems in some cases, mostly with webapps and upload feature (obviously because of incorrect implementation of this feature). I just gave him two regex, to detect if the file name is complete or if the user hasn't tried extension at all